# SqlKata - make paging query async

Tags: asynchronous, paging, sqlkata

I have created the following class to make all my queries paged, but i don't know how to make the final query asynchronous, is it possible with SqlKata?

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    public PagedList(List<T> items, int totalCount, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalCount = totalCount;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        CurrentPage = pageNumber;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalCount / (double)pageSize);
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(Query query, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = query.AsCount();
        var items = query.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).???;
    }
}
```

So after "Take(pageSize)" in the last query I see no SelectAsync or GetAsync. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why not use the built-in method `PaginateAsync`?

Comment: i dont get this option at all. i mean the passed in query does not have nothing about pagination. maybe im passing in the wrong type of object.

Comment: Install the `SqlKata.Execution` nuget and check this https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/fetching-records

Comment: thanks, i had that but was not using it. I need to pass in XQuery query for the async methods to show up.